# How do I handle errors that are already handled by another error?

Tags: java

I am connecting to a website using Jsoup. I have inserted a `.timeout` to check if the website times out.

Because I already handle `IOException`, my IDE is not allowing me to put another catch for `SocketTimeOutException`, which is fair, I guess.

Is there a way to tell from `IOException` what is the error?
I'd like to have specific debugging output for different errors, so that I can keep the code clean and efficient.

Here is my code (yes, some variables are missing, they are pretty simple though and not really necessary):

```
Document doc = null;

try
    {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(Url).proxy(proxy).userAgent(userAgent).timeout(10000).get();
    }
catch (IOException e)
    {
        if (...)
            {
                if(specificThread.running == false) {
                    System.out.println("Thread got interrupted! Link visited -> "+ Url);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

                try
                    {
                        System.out.println("Localhost detected! If this happens, you're stupid");
                        doc = Jsoup.connect(Url).userAgent(userAgent).get();
                    }
                catch (IOException e1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Couldn't connect to " + Url + " , localhost was detected.");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(-1);
                    }
                catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Malformed URL detected ->  " + Url) ;
                    }
            }
        else
            {
                System.out.println("Couldn't connect to " + Url);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error)
    {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL detected ->  " + Url);
    }
catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException error) //IDE Is blocking this
    {
        //Handle error here
    }
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the catch for the `SocketTimeoutException` before the catch for the `IOException`.

Exception handling works by looking through a table until a matching exception type is found. As such, more specific exceptions have to come before more general exceptions, in order that they can be matched.

---

This is described in [JLS Sec 14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21), "Unreachable Statements":

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is unreachable.
>
> ...
>
> - A catch block `C` is reachable iff both of the following are true:
>
>   - ...
>   - There is no earlier catch block A in the try statement such that the type of C's parameter is the same as or a subclass of the type of A's parameter.

So, you just need to make sure there is no earlier catch block catching a superclass parameter.

Comment: Oh man I feel really stupid now. Thanks, will accept in 10 minutes (SO not allowing me to accept the answer)